# jsf - "Cannot find component with expression"

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces and a component within one `layoutUnit` must update another component which is within another `layoutUnit`:

```
<p:layout>
  <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="275" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
    <h:form id="formWest">
      <div id="west">
        <ui:insert name="west"></ui:insert>
      </div>
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <p:layoutUnit id="layout_center" position="center">
    <h:form id="formCenter">
      <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
      </div>
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

The error message is: `Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "formWest:execucao" referenced from "formCenter:form:mapaGoogle".`

The components that need to be updated are inside `td` so I did `<td jsf:id="execucao">`, for example.

Comment: can you post the jsf page you are referring to these components?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you know when you refer components from another form you have to attach the form ID to the component Id.

You also need to know that you have to attach another `:` before the form ID, when refereing the compnent in different form.

Example:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:inputText id="input1" />
</h:form>
```

Now if I want to update the `input1` from another form I have to use:

```
:form1:input1
```

Example:

```
<h:form id="form2">
   <p:commandButton update=":form1:input1" />
</h:form>
```

In your case use:

```
:formWest:execucao
```

Comment: Can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018559/update-select-one-menu-from-another-page

Comment: `p:page` adds another id to the final id you have to provide in `update` attribute. `p:page id="master"`, then `h:form id="form-list-financial-receipt"` and then `p:dataTable id="table-list-financial-receipt"` and the final component's id is: `:master:form-list-financial-receipt:table-list-financial-receipt`. Out of a real-life FLOSS project.